# How do I email Google Maps directions (*not* just a *link* to directions)?

Tags: gmail, google-maps

I sometimes need to email a list of directions that I need to be available offline. So, emailing a *link* to Google Maps directions doesn't work. I want to email all of the directions.

I've tried just copying the page and emailing with Gmail but the markup is fouled up and unreadable (in IE10 and Chrome).

Comment: How about copying the "Print" view? Hit the "print" button to get a simplified view and copy that (rather than actually printing).

Comment: Or printing them to PDF and emailing the PDF file.

Answer (score 2):

First press the `Print` button, and then either:

1. Print the contents of the window to a PDF file (using a tool such as doPDF), or
2. Save the contents of the window using your browser's equivalent of

   "Save Page As" ==> "Web Archive" / "Web Page, complete".

   If the archive consists of multiple files then optionally zip them together into a single file for convenience.
3. Mail the PDF or the web archive file(s)